# Multiple UIAlertControllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app there are scenarios where multiple alerts could come. But as in iOS8 UIAlertview turned to UIAlertController, i am not able to show multiple alerts as you can not present two or more controllers at the same time.

How can I achieve this using UIAlertController?

Comment: You can, one solution is to embed the controller in a UIWindow, alternatively just go with UIAlertView

Answer (score 9):

Here is the method to show multiple alertControllers :

```
        UIAlertController *av = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:msg preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:kAlertOk
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                       {

                                       }];
        [av addAction:cancelAction];

        UIWindow *alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
        alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
        [alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
        [alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:av animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I asked because it seems odd to create a new `UIWindow` for this purpose. I thought maybe it was something tailored to OSX programming where multiple windows is common.

Comment: I do not recommend to make multiple windows for one screen. It can cause several problems like keyboard management and so on.

Answer (score 6):

You can keep track of a list of alerts to show in your view controller as an instance variable, say

```
NSMutableArray *alertsToShow;
```

You can present the first UIAlertController, and add a UIAlertAction in which you present the next alert (if applicable), with a recursive-like method:

```
- (void)showAlertIfNecessary {
    if (alertsToShow.count == 0)
        return;

    NSString *alert = alertsToShow[0];
    [alertsToShow removeObjectAtIndex:0];

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController
                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title"
                          message:alert
                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction 
        actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                {
                    [self showAlertIfNecessary];
                }];
    [alertController addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Note that this can get very annoying to the user, if he/she needs to click through a lot of messages. You might consider combining them into a single message.

Comment: Okay, so the issue is that alert we are showing based on webservice response and sometimes firing 2-3 webservice at the same time. And suppose connection lost so all webservice firing the alert. So suppose on every failure there is a common method which gets call and show the alert.

Comment: *Especially* in the case you're describing, I do not want (as a user) to dismiss 4 times a message telling me the same thing.

Comment: Okay, so with all these comments i can conclude that its not possible with UIAlertController. But this is very bad then, but there are scenarios where we need to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Swift version for @Bejibun's answer above:

```
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "New Message", message: "Message Body", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
       alertView.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }))

    let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
    alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
    alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
    alertWindow.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Don't work on iOS 13 but in iOS 12 working, any idea for IOS 13?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot show multiple alerts simultaneously, and if you were doing so before, you were behaving badly. Rethink your interface.

You can easily present alerts *in succession*, which is all you really need:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "One", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Next", style: .Default, handler: {
    _ in
    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Two", message: nil, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler:nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: 2015 WWDC talk on NSOperations had some really good insights of managing these kinds of situations using NSOperation dependencies, far cleaner:)

Comment: Absolutely. I'm not saying this code is a good idea. I'm just showing that it can be done — and, in particular, I'm saying that multiple simultaneous alerts are impossible.

Comment: Just been contemplating our responsibility to newcomers in providing lasting solutions versus quick hacks. Wonder how this can be achieved on SO or whether we just let newcomers make the same mistakes we did:)

Comment: Not at all sir, just thinking out loud:)

Comment: @matt Alerts can come from different places in an app asynchronously. Why is that bad behaviour? Happens in iOS apps too. What to do in those situation? Things worked so nicely in with `UIAlertView` :-(

Comment: @meaning-matters Airplanes can arrive at any time. Therefore it's just fine if they all smash into each other trying to land at once? No! We have air traffic controllers to line them up so they use the runway one at a time. As Daniel Galasko's first comment says, you can use NSOperation to help with this.

Comment: Nonsense! You can't change reality, so no matter the implementation, alerts need to be shown one after the other as well. With `UIAlertView` this was taken care of by the air traffic controller called iOS. But now it seems we have to invent our own air traffic control. You seem to regard writing more (not so simple) code for the same result an improvement; well, I don't. I reached out to Apple, and they suggest to post a feature request; there you have it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to present it on a top presented controller, you can use this extension:

```swift
extension UIViewController {

    var topController: UIViewController {
        presentedViewController?.topController ?? self
    }
}
```

```swift
self.topController.present(alert, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I am pretty late for this but still posting as It might be useful for someone looking for this though Apple doesn't recommend multiple alerts stacking thats why they deprecated this UIAlertView from to UIAlertController implementation.

I have created a AQAlertAction subclass for UIAlertAction. You can use it for staggering Alerts, the usage is same as you are using UIAlertAction. All you need to do is import [AQMutiAlertFramework](https://github.com/UpliftX/AQMultiAlertFramework) in your project or you can include class also (Please refer [Sample project](https://github.com/UpliftX/AQMultiAlertTest) for that). Internally It uses binary semaphore for staggering the Alerts until user handle action associated with current alert displayed. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSAlertView](https://github.com/sspbond007/JSAlertView) which handles both UIAlertView and UIAlertController APIs.

It handles multiple alerts fired at same time, very well. It also provide super easy methods for displaying simple alerts.

Comment: is **JS**AlertView stands for your name first letters ? :P

Answer (score 0):

You can Find Top Most View Controller using this Function.

```
func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    if let nav = base as? UINavigationController {
        return topViewController(nav.visibleViewController)
    }
    if let tab = base as? UITabBarController {
        if let selected = tab.selectedViewController {
            return topViewController(selected)
        }
    }
    if let presented = base?.presentedViewController {
        return topViewController(presented)
    }
    return base
}
```

Present `UIAlertController` Using this Method through. like,

```
topViewController()?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Method Info:** `topViewController()` find a top Most presented view controller, 
`UIAlertController` supper class is `UIViewController`.

first `UIAlertController` is open normal in top presented view controller, try to open a second `UIAlertController` then `topViewController()` given first alert view. so no any `UIAlertController` missed.