# Display multiple UIAlerts using UIAlertController

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

I got a scenario where I need to show multiple alerts at once.

I am using UIAlertController , so I am able to present only one view controller at once.

I tried the solutions posted on stack overflow which are not working.

How can I achieve this. Please don't suggest me that its bad idea to display multiple alerts once but this is rare scenario where I am going to do this. SO its ok.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you wan it to be, especially not clear the word "at once". They should be each on top of other or next to each other, how many alerts should be  at all ?

Comment: I think, this answer may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31410422/multiple-uialertcontrollers-in-ios

Comment: @mihatel yes I need on top of another and so that user won't get feeling multiple popups once.

Comment: @AbhishekMitra mentioned solution was not working so I have posted question.

Comment: @santhosh https://stackoverflow.com/a/31410611/6165231 this answer working fine, just need to convert it in swift 3/4, this is working on one by one basis though.. Thanks