# WKWebView: App crashing with 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' exception because 'Completion handler passed to X was not called'

Tags: javascript, ios, wkwebview

The exception below occurs when attempting to show two JavaScript alert boxes at the same time in a WKWebView on iOS. The app crashes as a result.

> 2017-12-23 00:46:29.434 Couch[3192:3428809] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Completion handler passed to -[XViewController
>   webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:completionHandler:]
>   was not called'

Here's the WKWebView delegate function in question:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage message: String, initiatedByFrame frame: WKFrameInfo,
             completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
        completionHandler()
    }))

    if let presenter = alertController.popoverPresentationController {
        presenter.sourceView = self.view
        presenter.sourceRect = CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY, width: 0, height: 0)
    }
    if presentedViewController == nil {
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the first `UIAlertController` is (being) presented, `presentedViewController` is no longer `nil`. Then your delegate method doesn't present the second/next `UIAlertController` and silently returns. Yet, you still need to call the `completionHandler()`.

```
if presentedViewController == nil
{
    // You get here for the second alert box, which is not shown.
    present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
    completionHandler()
}
```

The second, third, ... `UIAlertController` never appears. If that's not what you want look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31410422/1971013) for example.

Comment: interesting, will try this out!

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work. for some reason the else condition doesn't even get called for the second alert. (we put a breakpoint at the else condition and higher up in the function.)

Comment: The first does and the second alert does not appear on screen right? Perhaps `presentedViewController` is set a bit later. As an experiment you could add a `var isPresented: Bool = false` to your class, which you set just above `present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)` and change my code to `if !isPresented`. And of course reset `isPresented` appropriately in `addAction`'s block.

Comment: correct, the first alert appears. clicking the button that shows the alert is what causes the app to crash. thanks for your help!

Comment: what does the experiment accomplish? for some reason the whole function isn't getting called the second time, will this help with that situation? thanks again for your help!

Comment: Forget the experiment then; I assumed the function was called twice. Some thoughts: 1. Make sure the function is called for the first JS alert. 2. Try with one JS alert. 3. Is `completionHandler()` called?

Comment: 1. Yup, it's called on the first alert but not the second. 2. The app does not crash with only one alert. 3. Yes, completionHandler gets called the first time.

Comment: Actually sorry, `completionHandler` never gets called the first time because the OK button on the JavaScript alert never gets pressed. Any suggestions on what to do now?

Comment: Wow, difficult! Have you tried calling `completionHandler()` after a short delay; so not waiting for the alert? I'd just stip the function for now and just put a delayed `completionHandler()` in there: `self.dispatchQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) { `completionHandler() }`
                    {

Comment: ^^^^ Before you wrote "Actually, sorry ...".

Comment: Are both JS alert()'s, so prompt() or confirm()? There's both a JS and iOS alert?

Comment: we're using wkwebview to render pages written in HTML/JS so if someone creates a JS alert box it appears via wkwebview. note this problem only appears on ipads because of the way popovers are handled where you can interact with the page even if the alert remains on screen. (on iphones, you don't have the option of interacting with the page until the javascript alert is dismissed.)

Comment: for more context, the app is a runtime environment for running HTML/JS apps on your device without needing a server (and also offers access to the device clipboard and the ability to make web requests via GET and POST methods).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas from a distance. Good luck, I hope you can find a way out soon!